# Error con servicio de MySQL en VPS contratado

Tags: mysql, delphi

Tengo contratado un VPS donde tengouna base de datos mysql para utilizar mi aplicacion hecha en Delphi.

El caso es que ya lo tengo configurado de hecho puedo abrir la base de satos desde cualquier gestor.
Pero cuando se abre mi app en Delphi, una aplicacion de escritorio, ante cualquier update o insert me aparece un mensaje:

MySQL Server has gone away.

El caso es que trabajo con TClientDataSet, y con la base de datos en local no daba ese error.
No se que configuracion de mi servidor debo modificar.

Comment: Supongo que el servidor MySQL está cerrando la conexión cuando pasa cierto tiempo inactiva.  Puedes re-configurar el MySQL, pero también podrías implementar un mecanismo de re-conexión en tu aplicación para que, de cara al usuario, no falle. Supongo que la solución ideal es la combinación de ambas. Por la primera parte, qué te devuelve esta sentencai en tu servidor: `show variables like "%timeout%";`

Comment: Interesan particularmente ` interactive_timeout` y `wait_timeout`. Sugiero también que agregues la etiqueta mySQL, pues en realidad el problema está relacionado con el motor MySQL y no tanto con el lenguaje en el que está escrito el cliente.

Comment: Gracias jachguate una vez mas.. Logre solucionarlo aumentando el valor de wait timeout y max allowed packet. Y el tema de la reconexion es que tengo todos los insert y tablas conectados a TClientDataSets. El caso es que nunca toco el componente TSqlConnection salvo en el evento onCreate del dataModule.

Comment: Excelente, @Caruso, te dejé una respuesta para que esto no quede en comentarios. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que seguramente está ocurriendo es que la configuración *defualt* del MySQL está botando las conexiones que están inactivas durante algún tiempo. Para una aplicación de escritorio, seguro quieres aumentar este tiempo a valores mucho más altos que los que tenga actualmente

Ejecuta el siguiente comando en el servidor:

```
show variables like "%timeout%";
```

Te va a devolver algo como

```
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| connect_timeout          | 5     |
| delayed_insert_timeout   | 300   |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout | 50    |
| interactive_timeout      | 28800 |
| net_read_timeout         | 30    |
| net_write_timeout        | 60    |
| slave_net_timeout        | 3600  |
| table_lock_wait_timeout  | 50    |
| wait_timeout             | 28800 |
+--------------------------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Son de particular interés `interactive_timeout` y `wait_timeout`.

Puedes cambiar sus valores con el comando `set global`, por ejemplo:

```
set global wait_timeout=1800;
set global interactive_timeout=36000;
```

Más información en la documentación:

- [interactive_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout)
- [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)

Dicho esto, ya que el servidor está remoto, también te recomendaría implementar algún mecanismo de re-conexión a tu aplicación, de manera que el usuario no pierda siempre su trabajo si se pierde la conexión a Internet mientras procesa algún registro.